# Agregar una ruta nueva en un RESTful y utilizarlo en un form Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

buenas tardes, estoy en un problema que no puedo resolver,
agregue una nueva ruta en un controlador restful asi(lo encontre en internet)

```
Route::get('admin/store_productos','AdminController@store_productos');
Route::resource('admin','AdminController');
```

pero estoy ocupando esta ruta para pasar unos datos desde un form:

```
   {!!Form::open(['route'=>'admin.store_productos', 'method'=>'POST','files' => true])!!}
   <div class="row">
    {!!Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'input-field col  s12','placeholder'=>'Inserte Nombre del articulo'])!!}
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    {!!Form::text('precio',null,['class'=>'input-field col  s12','placeholder'=>'Inserte precio del articulo'])!!}
  </div>
  <div class="row"> 
    {!!Form::text('descripcion',null,['class'=>'input-field col  s12','placeholder'=>'Inserte descripcion del articulo'])!!}
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    {!!Form::file('path')!!}
  </div>
  {!!Form::submit('Registrar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

y me tira error Route [admin.store_productos] not defined.
alguien sabe por que?

Comment: ya probaste admin/store_productos en tu Form? en ves de admin.store_productos.

Comment: ya, pero me sale Route [admin/store_productos] not defined

Answer (score 0):

No estas asignando un nombre a la ruta, normal q te diga que la ruta no esta definida, prueba con :

```
Route::get('admin/store_productos','AdminController@store_productos')->name('admin.store_productos');
Route::resource('admin','AdminController');
```